# Unable to send messages to topic in Kafka Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have a producer code where am sending messages to Kafka. I was able to send messages till yesterday. From today I am unable to send messages. Not sure if it's version compatible issue. There are no failures or error messages, code gets executed, but it's not sending messages.

Below are the Python module versions:

`kafka-python==2.0.1`
`Python 3.8.2`

Below is my code:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='127.0.0.1:9092')
producer.send('Jim_Topic', b'Message from PyCharm')
producer.send('Jim_Topic', key=b'message-two', value=b'This is Kafka-Python')
```

I tries logging the behavior as well, but no idea why producer gets closed:

```
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=127.0.0.1:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: connecting to 127.0.0.1:9092 [('127.0.0.1', 9092) IPv4]
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=127.0.0.1:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
INFO:kafka.producer.kafka:Closing the Kafka producer with 0 secs timeout.
INFO:kafka.producer.kafka:Proceeding to force close the producer since pending requests could not be completed within timeout 0.
INFO:kafka.producer.kafka:Kafka producer closed

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: If this is a local installation of Kafka, can you try writing to a separate topic. Also send the strings as is and don't convert them to binary strings

Comment: I did that. Am able to send messages from kafka-producer console to kafka-consumer console. But am unable to do the same through python

Comment: No I meant try to send the messages to a separate topic with the same code

Comment: I tried that as well, created a new topic `Kafka_RND`, still am unable to send messges

Comment: Is that the entirety of your code? if not, could share the remaining part

Comment: This is the complete code

Comment: Added the logs as well. Not sure why producer gets closed

Comment: Your code runs fine for me against my local broker. Can you check your Kafka broker log file for any errors or messages to suggest it is in bad health?

Comment: I just used `producer.flush()` and it worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding `producer.flush()` at the end helped me to resolve the issues.  Any outstanding messages will be flushed (delivered) before actually committing the transaction

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='127.0.0.1:9092')
producer.send('Jim_Topic', b'Message from PyCharm')
producer.send('Jim_Topic', key=b'message-two', value=b'This is Kafka-Python')
producer.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code. I have picked it up from the kafka-python documentation and tried it on my local Kafka instance

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json
def on_send_success(record_metadata):
    print(record_metadata.topic)
    print(record_metadata.partition)
    print(record_metadata.offset)


def on_send_error(excp):
    log.error('I am an errback', exc_info=excp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    target_topic = "Jim_Topic"
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['127.0.0.1:9092'],retries=5, key_serializer=lambda x: json.dumps(x).encode("ascii"), value_serializer=lambda x: json.dumps(x).encode("ascii"))
    messages = [{key:"message_one",value:"Message from PyCharm"},{key:"message_two",value:"This is Kafka-Python"}]
    for msg in messages:
      producer.send(target_topic,msg).add_callback(on_send_success).add_errback(on_send_error)

    producer.flush(timeout=10) # this forcibly sends any messages that are stuck.
    producer.close(timeout=5)
```

Comment: Still its same. Messages are not sent

Comment: I changed the code to send Json messages, can you check it now?